# Log4j Rolling File appender uses wrong logfile

Tags: log4j, appender

my first question - Please Keep calm ;-)

our Problem is, that log4j uses the wrong logfile. Our configuration is a simple DailyRollingFileAppender

```
log4j.appender.dx4wsa=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dx4wsa.File=${env.WFL_DIR}/log/dx4wsa-agents.log
log4j.appender.dx4wsa.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.dx4wsa.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dx4wsa.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}: %5p %-30c{1} %-50x %m%n
```

What we see is, that sometimes the logger uses old logfiles after rolling over. For example here

```
dx4wsa-agents.log.2016-10-12-18:12.10.2016 20:39:03:  INFO VorgangLoeschen                21974690                                           Start executing agent on process instance = 21974690 and work item = 14f27076-f31f-48a7-849d-669189918730
```

You can see here, that this step is from 20:39:03 and the Logfile already rotated - it's the 18:00 Logfile. An "ls -ltr" Shows you the last Access.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tpdx4wf2 gpdoxis4     61944 Oct 12 17:59 dx4wsa-agents.log.2016-10-12-17
-rw-r--r-- 1 tpdx4wf2 gpdoxis4  51668039 Oct 12 17:59 dx4wsa-agents.log.2016-10-12-16
-rw-r--r-- 1 tpdx4wf2 gpdoxis4  40437528 Oct 12 19:59 dx4wsa-agents.log.2016-10-12-19
-rw-r--r-- 1 tpdx4wf2 gpdoxis4   1463292 Oct 12 20:54 dx4wsa-agents.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tpdx4wf2 gpdoxis4  67702368 Oct 12 20:54 dx4wsa-agents.log.2016-10-12-18
```

Today we had a release and, stopped the Server, killed all Java-Threads deployed new Jar-Files and restarted the Server at 19:00!!! And log4j logged in the 18:00 file?